# SSRS Expression - Subtracting the Sums, when one group is a parameter

Tags: reporting-services, subtraction

I am trying to Subtract two scenarios from each other in a SSRS report. One scenario is a constant, 'Actuals' the other is a dynamic forecast scenario and set by a parameter. Here is the code I am trying:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value,CDbl(Fields!CAD.Value),0))-
   sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",CDbl(Fields!CAD.Value),0))
```

I have also tried:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value,Fields!CAD.Value,0))-
   sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",Fields!CAD.Value,0))
```

The report runs but I get an error in the line where this expression is entered.

Comment: Is your CAD field a decimal? Is so, you'd need to convert the zero - `CDEC(0)`. If not, can you see what the error is in the Visual Studio preview? It will usually give you a vague idea of the issue.

Comment: Yes Sir it is decimal. I will try CDEC

Comment: I tried this but still got the #error. I am working SSRS Report Builder so the error is non-descript. =sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value,CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),0))-
   sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),0))

Comment: I'd probably start by just trying to display one half the expression to see if you can narrow the error down. The expression looks OK assuming `1` The field names are spelled correctly (case sensitive) `2` the expression is placed in a textbox that has the correct context (e.g. not in a stand alone textbox) otherwise the scope would have to be specified (e.g. `SUM(IIF(..., ..., ...), "myDataSet")` )

Comment: I feel we are so close. I did add the total row 'Outside Group - Below'. That may make sense. I tried the following and got the same error. =sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value,CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),0),"dsAccount8910_2200") -
 sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),0),"dsAccount8910_2200")

Comment: If you're converting CAD to CDEC, you should convert the zero to CDEC. Otherwise you're summing two different types, which may be your error.

Comment: That, CDEC(0), helped and allowed the second part of the expression (when used by itself) to return the correct values. The problem appears to be in the portion of the equation with the parameter.=sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value,CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),CDEC(0))) -
 sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),CDEC(0)))

Comment: Should I be using 'Is'? Like Fields!Scenario_Name.Value Is Parameters!ScenarioName.Value......instead of Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value   ???

Comment: The `=` *should* work as is. Your parameter isn't Multi-Value, is it? What's the parameter type? Is it a number and the field a string?

Comment: The Parameter isn't set to multiple values. The Parameter type is text.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone the error has been fixed. CDEC helped.

Answer (score 0):

The CDEC was important to both the CAD.value and the 0. The Parameter value needs a (0) as in the final expression that works.

```
enter code here=Sum(IIf(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value=Parameters!ScenarioName.Value,CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),CDEC(0))) -
```

Sum(iif(Fields!Scenario_Name.Value="Activity Actuals",CDEC(Fields!CAD.Value),CDEC(0)))